# Best way to store 1000s of small images (<5k) either in MongoDb or S3?

Tags: image, mongodb, amazon-s3

I'm planning on storing 1000s (hopefully even millions some day) of profile images from facebook and twitter. Their usual size is less than 5k.

What is the best way to do this either in MongoDB or on Amazon S3 and avoid disk fragmentation  or similar issues?

Any pointers/tips on the do's and don'ts would be very helpful as well.

Comment: I have a similar problem

Comment: I have about 5 million files already, I am using raid 1 disks but the latency time is getting higher. I dont know what I should do either.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, publish profile images from the associated Social site (Facebook, Twitter, etc), but if you have to store uploaded images onto S3, rather than reading the file (from S3) and re-stream it to your user, you can enable the "Website" feature and have your images linked to S3 directly.

So your html image tag will be like:

```
<img src="http://<amazon s3 - website - endpoint>/<image filename>" title="something">
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just store the usernames instead? The profile image can be accessed via the Facebook Graph API (just replace "username" with any Facebook user's username). You'll also save the work of keeping the profile pictures updated.

```
<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/username/picture" />
```

Comment: The issue there is page load times. There can be anywhere between 30 (realistic) to 100+ (edge case) images per page. This will result in twice the # of http calls (First to get the image fromt he url you posted above and the second to the redirected, generally a CDN, url that facebook returns for that particular image). This would drastically impact the page load times.

Comment: Yeah, possibly. May be populate images after page load, via Javascript?

Comment: The question is more about storing the images, or for that matter, any type of small files. I'm keen to get the community's thoughts on the storage aspects. The Javascript option is perhaps the last resort if I don't find a better solution.